# How to read array posted from form repeater

Tags: php

How to read array posted from form repeater

the best is the array got from a form post..

```
Array ( 
    [products] => Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( 
            [pid] => 1 
            [qty] => 2 
        ) 
        [1] => Array ( 
            [pid] => 1 
            [qty] => 2 
        ) 
        [2] => Array ( 
            [pid] => 1 
            [qty] => 2 
        ) 
    ) 
)
```

my question is how to read value like this:

$pid[1]= 1

$qty[1] = 1

Comment: `$thePid = $arr['products'][0]['pid'];`

Comment: you need to use $products = $_POST['products']; echo $products[0]['pid'];

Comment: @RiggsFolly   -- thanks for guiding  but nothing works.

Comment: @Girish Sasidharan - thanks for guiding but did does not works.

Comment: Nothing working, and yet you accept an answer that say exactly what I did

Comment: Sorry MR.RiggsFolly  @RiggsFolly the answer that i accept is more clear than yours...   iam not a developer so i cant understand the way you answerd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the array values like this.

```
<?php
    $array = array("products"=> [["pid" => 1 , "qty" => 2 ],
                                 ["pid" => 2 , "qty" => 3 ],
                                 ["pid" => 3 , "qty" => 4 ]]);
    echo "PId: " . $array["products"][0]["pid"] . "<br>";
    echo "qty: " . $array["products"][0]["qty"] . "<br><br>";
    print_r($array);
    ?>
```

see the PHP fiddle for the working [version](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/p6is-rknk)

Comment: ```  echo $_POST["products"][0]["pid"]; ```